# How does jdbc-outbound-gateway transaction management works, when trying to update n (n here 100 or more than that)?

Tags: spring-integration

I have implemented below approach to update the n number of row (n is 100 for ex) in Oracle DB through jdbc-outbound-gateway.

I am splitting the multiple notes object through splitter and trying to update the status in the database by using the JDBC-outbount-gateway. I am getting 100 to 300 notes object after splitting, which I am trying to update in the db.

Now, my questing , 
1) is jdbc-outbound-gateway going to open 100 database connection ? 
2)if yes, then please help , how I can do the same thing by opening only single db connection with jdbc-outbound-gateway?

Thanks, Soum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use direct channels and start a transaction before the splitter.

See [the documentation about transactions in Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html).

How you start the transaction depends on what is upstream of the splitter.

Comment: Thanks much Gary ! I will check and get back to you for any further clarifications.